# Ancient Chinese method to calculating $\pi$

Tags: pi

I'm trying to understand the following passage from Boyer's and Merzbach's [History of Mathematics](https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema00boye):

[image: page 203]

[image: Fig. 9.1]

The question I have is: how does the author derive that $w^2=2rv$?

Comment: $w^2 = v^2 + \frac{s^2}{4}$, $v=r-u$, and $u^2 = r^2 - \frac{s^2}{4}$. Substituting $v$ and $\frac{s^2}{4}$ in the first equation from information in the latter two equations gives us $w^2 = (r-u)^2 + r^2 - u^2 = 2r^2 - 2ru =2r(r-u)=2rv$ so $w^2 = 2rv$

Comment: @Sam That's a full answer. Why have you put it in the comment section?

Comment: @Arthur It felt wrong to put such a short answer as a proper answer 

Comment: @Sam you can also post as "Community Wiki" if you don't want the reputation for it, but at least the question gets an answer that can be accepted.

Comment: @Sam If the answer to a question is a simple calculation, then the answer to a question is a simple calculation. It still belongs in the answer section. Because it's an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing out Sam's solution from the comment section:

$w^2=v^2+\frac{s^2}4$, $v=r−u$, and $u^2=r^2−\frac{s^2}4$. Substituting $v$ and $\frac{s^2}4$ in the first equation from information in the latter two equations gives us $$w^2=(r−u)^2+r^2−u^2=2r^2−2ru=2(r−u)=2rv$$ so $w^2=2rv$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much